# How to know if a particular part of a mesh has a bump in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, raycasting

I want to scan a part of the mesh where I raycast with a boundary value like a square on the mesh. I need to know if there is a bump on that particular part which I am raycasting. Can anyone tell if this is possible or not in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

**First case, If you want to find the extruded mesh area.**

I don't know certain algorithm to detect extruded mesh. but I'm pretty sure it **would be possible**.

Most mesh algorithms just require vertices, normals, and tangents. so the list of functions below will be suffice for you, no matter what algorithm you choose.

[Mesh-vertices Unity Document](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-vertices.html)

[Mesh-normals Unity Document](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-normals.html)

[Mesh-tangents Unity Document](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-tangents.html)

**Second case, If the bump you're talking about means a NormalMap**

use function below to get the UV of the raycasting point in Mesh.

And, you have to pick up specific material that has normalmap through MeshRenderer.

[RaycastHit-textureCoord Unity Document](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-textureCoord.html)

[Finding material of Renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html)

Comment: Thanks @ggzerosum!!
The bump I am talking about is the mesh not the normal map.
My requirement which I am working on is, I will raycast a pointer to a mesh and the pointer will have a square or rectangle around it.
Within the square/rectangle area, how do I know if there is a bump or dip?

Please help on this.